# Example of function that is in $C^\infty([0,\infty))\cap L^1((0,\infty))$ but not in $W^{1,1}(0,\infty)$

Tags: solution-verification, sobolev-spaces, smooth-functions

> I need to give an example of function that is in $C^\infty([0,\infty))\cap L^1((0,\infty))$ but not in $W^{1,1}(0,\infty)$.

We know that if a function $u$ belongs to $W^{1,1}(0,\infty)$, then $u(x) \to 0$ for $x \to \infty$.

I though like this: we forget a moment that must be in $C^\infty([0,\infty))$, take $\varphi _n$ as the function that is defined only in $[n,n+1)$ and make a triangle of height $1$ over the segment $[n,n+\frac{1}{n^2}]$.Then we define
$$\varphi(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \varphi_n(x).$$

For definition we have $\varphi \in L^1(0,\infty)$ and it's quite clear that $\limsup_{x\to \infty} \varphi(x) = +1$ and $\liminf_{x\to \infty} \varphi(x) = 0$ so the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} \varphi(x)$ does not exists (in particular it's not equal to $0$).

To complete the answer, instead of taking $\varphi_n$ that forms a tringle, we can take $\varphi_n \in C^\infty([n,n+1))$ for example that makes a "stretched Gaussian".

What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me!

Comment: I'm not very sure about the fact that $\varphi$ does not go to $0$ for $x \to \infty$. Can anyone check this fact?

Comment: I edited the way I take the $\varphi_n$ so that it's clear that the limit at infinity is not $0$.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but for what I see on Wikipedia for [Meyers–Serrin theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meyers%E2%80%93Serrin_theorem) maybe the counterexample do not exist.